# Switch git account Android studio Mac

Tags: git, macos, android-studio, bitbucket

Recently I face a problem once I pulled commits using pull button in android studio I got this error:

```
Update failed
        Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
```

After I tried to execute the git pull command in terminal built-in android studio they asked me for a password for the wrong account(I used this account in another project)

**What I tried**

- I used these commands:
  `git config --global user.name "Bob"`
  `git config --global user.email "bob@example.com"` 
  but it's still ask me for the old account not the one I give it in the next command
- Delete all credentials in **Keychain access** and execute pull again(I thought it should ask me for the credentials again but that's didn't happened unfortunately)

Any ideas or suggestions

Thanks in Advance : )

Comment: `git config` is completely irrelevant. In fact, Git is pretty much irrelevant. This is about you authenticating with Bitbucket.

Comment: How do I can re-authenticating with bitbucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of recent changes in Bitbucket.

https://atlassian.community/t5/x/x/ba-p/1948231

Trying using the SSH-based cloning instead of username/password based.